# Way of finding input devices?

Tags: macos, terminal.app

In terminal is there a way for me to find all the input devices, eg keyboard and mouse? And more specifically get their thread id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In System Profiler (and its command-line equivalent `/usr/sbin/system_profiler`), there's a *Location ID* entry for devices, e.g.

```
                USB Receiver:

                  Product ID: 0xc52c
                  Vendor ID: 0x046d  (Logitech Inc.)
                  Version: 12,01
                  Speed: Up to 12 Mb/sec
                  Manufacturer: Logitech
                  Location ID: 0xfd131300 / 9
                  Current Available (mA): 500
                  Current Required (mA): 98
```